# Creating new table by using more than one Select statements

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have following three select statements:

```
Select a, b, c from Table1
Select p, q, r from Table2
Select x, y, z from Table3
```

I want to create a table by using these three select statements ( I mean by using 9 columns) so that I can use the query `Select a, b, c, p, q, r, x, y, z from table4`. Please help me to create a table like this.

Comment: How are the tables related?  How do we know which values for `a,b,c` go on the same row as which values for `p,q,r`?

Comment: You might think about using a Union to join-up the results.

Comment: @JNK there is a relation between those tables. all the first columns in the three tables a,p,x are same type. We can use joins with those columns. but the remaining columns are getting the values with some computations (Aggregate functions) and using sub queries.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this in a way that makes sense, at least, is by joining all the tables by a common field. For example:

```
Select a, b, c, p, q, r, x, y, z from 
Table1 join Table2 on Table1.a=Table2.p
       join Table3 on Table3.x=Table1.c
-- and so son
```

Now, the `join` could be an inner join (forcing match on both tables) or a left -or right- join.

Read up on [Joins.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)

Answer (score 0):

If your end result is the creation of a new table, try using the `SELECT INTO` statement

Something like this:

```
SELECT 
    Table1.a, Table1.b, Table1.c,
    Table2.p, Table2.q, Table2.r,
    Table3.x, Table3.y, Table3.z
INTO [Table4]
FROM [Table1]
INNER JOIN [Table2] ON Table1.a = Table2.p
INNER JOIN [Table3] ON Table1.c = Table3.x;
```

This is assuming the tables are related in some way